# Migrating encrypted rds to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to use encrypted RDS on AWS. I want to know it is possible export the database to my local mysql. How can I move the encrypted data if our requirements changes.

Is there a way decrypt AWS encrypted RDS with master key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily export the data from RDS via the `mysqldump` command without having to worry about the encryption at all.

Comment: What should i do for decrypt data. Data will come encrypted. Yes i have master key but may be rds usung some salt when encrypt data. Will i get plain data if i use mysldump command.

Comment: When you enable RDS encryption it encrypts the data transparently on the storage volumes used by RDS. The data isn't encrypted in the database's memory, if it was you wouldn't be able to query it. And you don't get encrypted data back in your query results. RDS provides encryption-at-rest and you can use SSL for encryption-in-motion. If you also want to encrypt certain fields in the database using KMS you would need to do that manually.

Comment: I think if you just created a small RDS instance with encryption enabled and used it for a minute all this would make much more sense to you.